# Correct Mathematical Equation for Image pixels transformation

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing, computer-vision

I have just transformed a sinusoidal channel to a straightened channel.
[image]
The psuedocode of the algorithm is:
[image: shown here]

I have mathematically formulated the algorithm as follows:
[image: shown here]

where `k` is, for example, `k = 80` (the reference row).

But it seems wrong mathematically.

Kindly tell me the correct mathematical notation for the algorithm and how should I incorporate value of `k` in the mathematical equation.

Comment: Please post your code rather than a link to an image of it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please post the image you are trying to adjust and the result you expect rather than a picture of a formula.

Comment: @Richardissimo I think it should be more clear from the psuedocode given in the image. I just need the mathematical formulation for the code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have edited the question and included the image of the sinusoidal channel and its corresponding straightened channel. It is already done in programming. I need mathematical equivalent notation for the algorithm, which is correct in  the equation i defined , but seems notation is not ok in mathematics

Comment: and what/how do you want to achieve?  as there are more approaches when each have different properties of he result ... for example you need to have the same density of points? same curvelength as resulting length  etc ... where is the problem exactly? `But it seems wrong mathematically.` is so vague can you be more specific? Also in which form you have the input? I mean the sin shape properties

Comment: @Spektre , Thanks for the comment. I have achieved what i want with my algorithm, I just need to formulate it correctly.